# What is the best way to store project specific config info in ruby Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I have rake tasks for getting the production database from the remote server, etc. It's always the same tasks but the server info changes per project. I have the code here: https://gist.github.com/868423 In the last task, I'm getting a @local_db_dir_path = nil error.

I don't think want to use shell environment variables because I don't want to set them up each time I use rake or open a new shell.

Comment: Someone on IRC suggested I use a global hash like $config = {:server => 'remote_hostname', :user => 'username' , etc... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick the settings in a YAML file, and read it like this:

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load("config.yaml") # or wherever

$remote_host = config['remote_host']
$ssh_username = config['ssh_username']
# and so on
```

Or you can just read one big config hash:

```
$config = YAML.load("config.yaml")
```

Note that I'm using globals here, not instance variables, so there's no chance of being surprised by variable scope.

config.yaml would then look like this:

```
--- 
remote_host: some.host.name
ssh_username: myusername
other_setting: foo
whatever: bar
```

I tend to keep a config.yaml.sample checked in with the main body of the code which has example but non-working settings for everything which I can copy across to the non-versioned config.yaml.  Some people like to keep their config.yaml checked in to a live branch on the server itself, so that it's versioned, but I've never bothered with that.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using capistrano for this, you could use mulitsage or just separate host setting to a task, example capistrano would look like this:

```
task :development do
  server "development.host"
end

task :backup do
  run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:dump"
  download "remote_path", "local_path"
end
```

and call it like this:

```
cap development backup
```

Comment: That's orthogonal to where the per-project config is stored.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could use capistrano and not their deploy tasks. For a PHP project, I don't need the whole release/current directory tree and apache does not have to be restarted. Cap just seems really complex. Although I do rails projects with cap, I am looking for something that I could easily explain to PHP programmers.

Comment: @Ivanoats capistrano is suited to do whatever you want, using current/release is not necessary although I find it very useful, for db migration you could use this script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246821/capistrano-howto-deploy-mysql-database-for-a-php-application/5319691#5319691